# xUnit tests fails when run all together

Tags: c#, xunit

I am getting this error message:

```
 chldr_shared.tests.EntryServiceTests.AddRemoveEntry_ActiveMember_Success
   Source: EntryServiceTests.cs line 27
   Duration: 1.9 sec

  Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

  Stack Trace: 
SqlEntriesRepository.Add(EntryDto newEntryDto) line 199
EntryService.AddEntry(EntryDto entryDto, String userId) line 24
EntryServiceTests.AddRemoveEntry_ActiveMember_Success() line 41
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

It  only shows up when I run all tests together, when run individually - no errors.
I think it has something to do with me using a single, real database for testing, which is by design, but maybe I need a better isolation?

Here's the code:

```
 public class EntryServiceTests
    {
        private IDataProvider _dataProvider;
        private EntryService _entryService;
        private static string _userId;

        public EntryServiceTests()
        {
            _dataProvider = TestDataFactory.CreateSqlDataProvider();
            _entryService = new EntryService(_dataProvider);

            var unitOfWork = _dataProvider.CreateUnitOfWork();
            _userId = unitOfWork.Users.GetRandomsAsync(1).Result.First().UserId;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task AddRemoveEntry_ActiveMember_Success()
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                // Arrange
                var unitOfWork = _dataProvider.CreateUnitOfWork(_userId);

                var user = (await unitOfWork.Users.GetRandomsAsync(1)).First();
                var source = (await unitOfWork.Sources.GetRandomsAsync(1)).First();

                var entryDto = TestDataFactory.CreateRandomEntryDto(user.UserId, source.SourceId);

                // Act
                await _entryService.AddEntry(entryDto, user.UserId);

                // Assert
                var insertedEntry = await _entryService.Get(entryDto.EntryId);
                var userRateRange = user.GetRateRange();

                Assert.Equal(entryDto.Content, insertedEntry.Content);
                Assert.Equal(userRateRange.Lower, insertedEntry.Rate);
                Assert.Equal(entryDto.Sounds[0].SoundId, insertedEntry.Sounds[0].SoundId);

                await _entryService.Remove(entryDto.EntryId, user.UserId);
                await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentException>(async () => await _entryService.Get(entryDto.EntryId));
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task AddEntry_InActiveUser_Fails()
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                // Arrange
                var unitOfWork = _dataProvider.CreateUnitOfWork(_userId);

                var user = TestDataFactory.CreateRandomUserDto();
                user.Status = chldr_data.Enums.UserStatus.Banned;
                await unitOfWork.Users.Add(user);

                var source = (await unitOfWork.Sources.GetRandomsAsync(1)).First();
                var entryDto = TestDataFactory.CreateRandomEntryDto(user.UserId, source.SourceId);

                // Act
                await Assert.ThrowsAsync<InvalidOperationException>(async () => await _entryService.AddEntry(entryDto, user.UserId));
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_NonExistingEntity_ThrowsException()
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                // Arrange
                var entityId = "non_existing_entity_id";

                // Act and Assert
                await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentException>(async () => await _entryService.Get(entityId));
            }
        }
```

The 199th line:

```
public override async Task<List<ChangeSetModel>> Add(EntryDto newEntryDto)
        {
            if (newEntryDto == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(newEntryDto.EntryId))
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            }

            var user = UserModel.FromEntity(await _dbContext.Users.FindAsync(_userId));
            if (user.Status != UserStatus.Active)
            {
                // The 199th line, the user.Status is always Active 
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            // Set rate
            newEntryDto.Rate = user.GetRateRange().Lower;
            foreach (var translationDto in newEntryDto.Translations)
            {
                translationDto.Rate = newEntryDto.Rate;
            }

            try
            {
                // Insert Entry entity (with associated sound and translation entities)
                var entry = SqlEntry.FromDto(newEntryDto, _dbContext);
                _dbContext.Add(entry);
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                // Set CreatedAt to update it on local entry
                newEntryDto.CreatedAt = entry.CreatedAt;

                var entryChangeSet = CreateChangeSetEntity(Operation.Insert, newEntryDto.EntryId);
                var resultingChangeSets = new List<ChangeSetModel>
                {
                    ChangeSetModel.FromEntity(entryChangeSet)
                };

                // Process added sounds
                foreach (var sound in newEntryDto.Sounds)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sound.RecordingB64))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var filePath = Path.Combine(_fileService.EntrySoundsDirectory, sound.FileName);
                    File.WriteAllText(filePath, sound.RecordingB64);
                }

                return resultingChangeSets;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.InnerException != null && ex.Message.Equals("Could not save changes. Please configure your entity type accordingly."))
                {
                    throw _exceptionHandler.Error(ex.InnerException);
                }
                throw _exceptionHandler.Error(ex);
            }
        }
```

The funny thing is that the test that fails, theoretically cannot have a user with status != Active, because I only have two users in the test database and both of them are Active, so this must be coming from the other test where I specifically create an invalid user and try to use it in Addition, not sure how it got so mixed up though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your problem that you are using single _dataProvider/_entryService entire time and you have concurrency issue because of that

Comment: @MaxNaumov I am newing it in the constructor and constructor should be running before  each test

Comment: You should create it in the scope of the method since you are using async operations. Multiple methods that use the same _dataProvider/_entryService can run simultaneously. Thus the problem.